# Is there a general theory about repetition of the same operator?

Tags: arithmetic

Is there a theory about repeating the same arithmetic operation? E.G. multiplication is a repetition of addition, and exponentiation is the repetition of multiplication.

Comment: Continuous has another meaning in math. Maybe “repeated” is a better term?

Comment: Yes thanks, mind spasm! :)

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia pages on [the Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) and [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Comment: I've no idea why this question is the subject of down-votes. It's a perfectly good question that leads to some interesting mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

As Rob Arthan pointed out in the comments, [Knuth's up arrow notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is the way to go, and the sequence is called the [hyperoperation sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation).

Answer (score 0):

**My answer is maybe less about giving an answer, and maybe more about giving some perspective. Maths is just convention; numbers don't have a meaning thought you can think about it the way you like.**

Actually, are you looking for algebra theory ? It all comes down to "how" you define operators. What you say that all operators can be reduced and it works well, it's perhaps because you are talking about complex numbers, but it might be true that:

$$ a^5 \neq a \times a \times a  \times a \times a $$

Take a look at rings if you haven't yet, and fields. Those are sets upon which you define an operator. There is no reason why the addition (or first law) would have anything in common with multiplication (second law). Actually, in group theory, one writes

$$ g^3 = g + g + g $$

if $g$ is an element of the group, and $+$ is the law inside the group. LHS is just a common, useful (short cut) notation.

Comment: -1. The tag is arithmetic, meaning OP is most likely not looking for answers related to abstract algebra. Unhelpful.

Comment: Also, don't submit an edit 'correcting' OP's grammar if you think "repeating" is spelled "repetiting".

Comment: @MicahWindsor Hi, I understand what you ve written, my proposition was to explore other realms, since the question could be understand either as the question of someone that already knows a lot about the field, or a totally newcommer. I took the bet about the second hypothesis. If someone don't know what algebra is, he will think arithmetic is all about operators, when actually it is the concern of algebra. What for grammar, sorry for that, actually I was more focused on the meaning of the question, not on grammar / spelling where I don't think I am good enough to give anyone a lesson.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I approved your edit btw :) thank you for the precision!

Comment: If the intention isn't to answer, your post belongs in the comment section. And thank you for approving the edit.